# Does anyone know how to extract dynamic group membership rules from AzureAD using Powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell

I am using a command but only the display name is returned with the membership rule column being blank

This is the script I used:

```
Get-AzureADMSGroup -Filter "groupTypes/any(c:c eq 'DynamicMembership')" -All:$true | Select-Object Displayname,MembershipRule
```

Comment: The old module has [issues](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-entra-azure-ad/missing-membershiprule-in-get-azureadmsgroup/m-p/2059791). Update to the [AZ](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Az/) module and use `Get-AzADGroup -Filter "groupTypes/any(c:c eq 'DynamicMembership')" | Select-Object Displayname,MembershipRule`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am using a command but only the display name is returned with the membership rule column being blank

Thanks to `jfrmilner` for suggesting the same point.

If you are using an old version of the `Az.Resources` module, try updating to the latest version.

Here is the updated command.

```
Install-Module -Name Az.Resources -AllowClobber
Get-AzADGroup -Filter "groupTypes/any(c:c eq 'DynamicMembership')" | Select-Object Displayname,MembershipRule
```

**Output:**

[image]

Reference:  [Get-AzADGroup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azadgroup?view=azps-10.2.0)